# ruby on rails create a custom xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi can i create a custom XML after filling a form in Ruby on rails view template.

Once i m done with capturing data i dono how to create an XML?

Could anyone help

What is exactly rxml and can I use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Builder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html) to generate your XML:

```
require "builder"

@xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
@xml.intruct!
@xml.mydoc do
    @xml.property "Data"
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks,
Aother question .I have created a dummy model class which is not extending active record

class RamOne
   attr_accessor :name,:city
 end

 Controller 

 def start
      @ramone = RamOne.new
              end
  def load_new
   @ramone = RamOne.new(params[:ramone])
   if @ramone.save
      redirect_to :action => ‘gen_xml’
   end
  end
   def gen_xml
    @xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
    @ramones = RamOne.find(:all)
    render :layout => false
  end

View captures name,city and has a submit action attached with load_new

error : wrong num of args(1 for 0 ) in load_new 
what is wrong?